# PHP preg_replace : matching words containing a dash

Tags: php, regex

I am facing a problem searching words in a string and converting them into links. How to make a search that considers words containing a "-" as whole word and not as 2 words separated by "-" ?

Here is an example, if I search for the word "exhaustive", my search function will also match the part of the word "non-exhaustive", although i  don't want this word to be matched.

```
$string = "Bla bla bla non-exhaustive blabla bla exhaustive";
$words = array('exhaustive','non-exhaustive');
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/i', '<a href=#>'.$word.'</a>',$string);
}

echo $string;
```

Result :

> Bla bla bla non-**exhaustive** blabla bla **exhaustive**

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You can explicitly prevent the hyphen: `'/\b[^\-]'.$word.'\b/i'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b[^\-]' . preg_quote($word) . '\b/i', '<a href=#>' . $word . '</a>',$string);
```

Should do the trick :)

*edit, Aleks did beat me with just 2 sec :p

Comment: Use [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote) on `$word` and I'll upvote you. :)